# QLabel border visible within QGridLayout

Tags: qt, qlabel, qframe

I'm facing a problem with UI design.

I'm using QT 4.6.2 with QTCreator 1.3.1

I have a QFrame with a background image that "draw" the grid see  image below

[image]

When i add a QLabel within the layout, when i run the app i see top left border. For test, i moved out the QLabel from the Layout and it works as expected (no border at all)

Do you have any idea about that?

Thanks in advance for your kindly help

Leo

Comment: share the .ui file

Comment: Also, Qt 4.6 is almost 10 years old, maybe you wanna update to Qt 5 and Qt Creator 4.6?

Comment: Unfortunately i'm working in an embedded system that does not allow ant update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using a style sheet to set the background of your QFrame. Something like this:

```
QFrame{
    background-image: url(picture.png);
}
```

Style sheet propagates to children widgets, so my idea is that your background is applied to the children QLabels as well.

Change your style sheet to this one (notice the dot at the beginning):

```
.QFrame{
    background-image: url(picture.png);
}
```

The dot selector will restrict the style sheet only to the children widgets of your QFrame that are of type QFrame, but won't apply it to inheriting classes like QLabel. See the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) to learn more about selectors.

Comment: I Will try on monday. Thanks for tour auggestion